# How can I refund an order fully via MWS feeds API?

Tags: api, feed, amazon-mws

I'm using the Amazon MWS feeds API to submit a feed, here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
<Header>
    <DocumentVersion>1.02</DocumentVersion>
    <MerchantIdentifier>xxx</MerchantIdentifier>
</Header>
<MessageType>OrderAdjustment</MessageType>
<Message>
    <MessageID>1</MessageID>
    <OrderAdjustment>
        <AmazonOrderID>xxx</AmazonOrderID>
        <ActionType>Refund</ActionType>
        <AdjustedItem>
            <AmazonOrderItemCode>xxx</AmazonOrderItemCode>
            <AdjustmentReason>GeneralAdjustment</AdjustmentReason>
        </AdjustedItem>
    </OrderAdjustment>
</Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

And I got the response as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
    <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.02</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>A1B4GJWW9XJ35M</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>ProcessingReport</MessageType>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <ProcessingReport>
            <DocumentTransactionID>282020017464</DocumentTransactionID>
            <StatusCode>Complete</StatusCode>
            <ProcessingSummary>
                <MessagesProcessed>1</MessagesProcessed>
                <MessagesSuccessful>0</MessagesSuccessful>
                <MessagesWithError>1</MessagesWithError>
                <MessagesWithWarning>0</MessagesWithWarning>
            </ProcessingSummary>
            <Result>
                <MessageID>1</MessageID>
                <ResultCode>Error</ResultCode>
                <ResultMessageCode>25</ResultMessageCode>
                <ResultDescription>We are unable to process the XML feed because one or more items are invalid. Please re-submit the feed.</ResultDescription>
            </Result>
        </ProcessingReport>
    </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

Questions:
1. If I want to refund this order fully can I ignore the  section?
2. In this order I do have only 1 item, I'm not sure if I use the correct , I got this from the order api OrderItemId

Comment: This order only have 1 item.

Answer (score 0):

Your error says

> We are unable to process the XML feed because one or more items are invalid. Please re-submit the feed.

That means the structure of your XML is invalid in some way.

After looking at the [documentation](https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/help/help-page.html/ref=au_200387280_cont_scsearch?ie=UTF8&itemID=200387280), it seems if you want to cancel the order entirely, you have to use the [order acknowledgement feed](https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/help/200387140?ref=ag_200387140_cont_200387280).

If you want to issue a partial refund or cancel one item in the order, you can use the order adjustment feed, which you have in your example.

According the the [XSD for order adjustments](https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/help/help-page.html/ref=au_200387280_cont_scsearch?ie=UTF8&itemID=200387280), you seem to missing ItemPriceAdjustments from the feed you are submitting.

Amazon needs to know how much to adjust the order for each item and you can get as granular as you need.

Comment: Thanks. I don't think I should use the order acknowledgement feed because we do this after customer request to refund an order.

Comment: I did checked the XSD https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/xsd/release_4_1/OrderAdjustment.xsd and I noticed the ItemPriceAdjustments can be none. Anyway I will do a test to see if it's ok.